# In UNIX, is it possible to "cat" a file over http?

Tags: bash, unix, cat

Here is what I want to do:

```
cat https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jplew/SyncDB/master/syncdb
```

This gives a "No such file or directory" error, because `cat`, evidently, cannot grab a remote file over HTTP. Is there another way to accomplish this?

**The Bigger Picture**

I'm trying to write an auto-update function for my bash script. It needs to determine if the local version of the script is different from the latest public version. If there's a difference, it should download the new release.

I figured that I could test this using:

```
diff [local file] [remote file]
diff syncdb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jplew/SyncDB/master/syncdb
```

But this gives the same problem as above: "No such file or directory". So my second idea was to try this:

```
cat https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jplew/SyncDB/master/syncdb | diff - syncdb
```

Because this script is used by the public, they don't have SSH access to the public github repo. Secondly, I prefer not to use `git diff` to compare files, because this requires that they have `git` installed, messes up the proper file location/structure, and also requires that they've cloned my repo, which I prefer to avoid as a requirement.

I know I could download the raw remote file using `curl` or `wget`, then `diff` them, but this defeats the whole purpose of checking to see if there are any changes before downloading.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe curl will help you

```
curl  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jplew/SyncDB/master/syncdb | diff - syncdb
```

Comment: I tend to use `wget -O -` but that's because that's how it was taught to me.  I always forget `curl`, although it's actually nicer to use.

Comment: Or just `diff <(curl ...) syncdb`

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using wget and then use cat to display the file's contents.

> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jplew/SyncDB/master/syncdb && cat syncdb

Comment: what's the advantage of this way compared to `curl`?

Comment: `wget -q -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jplew/SyncDB/master/syncdb` would be as good (or even better).